# How do I make only one nested div scrollable?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQjpH.png)

I want the red portion to remain fixed and only the blue portion to scroll when there is an overflow. (The red portion consists of 2 divs)

I am able to make the Entire thing scrollable, but I want the red to remain fixed.
(I have already tried position: fixed but it is not working properly, search and headers are getting on top of each other)

Comment: please read the guide, how to ask a good question at the stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make your `header` (i.e., red portion) in different component and `list` in different component and make `list component scrollable by giving it a fixed height`.

Created Sandbox representing the similar solution :-

https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-header-list-9gjvd7

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh; // if you want the container to fill the viewport's height
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```